Building separate objects from lengthy arrays in Powershell
I have an array of IPs that I want to add on to a URL. The array can be very long and the URL can only accept so many characters, so I need to break up the array of IPs ONLY when it reaches the max characters.
Let's say the max number of characters for a URL is 40. Either I want to base it off that character limit, or I could go by a certain number of IPs (for this example below it'd be 2).
`
$IPs = @('1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4', '5.5.5.5')
$URL = 'https://test.com/ips=$IPs' # this is 25 characters
if ($IPs -ge 15) {
foreach ($IP in $IPs) {
    $IPs| Where-Object $_.count -gt 2
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $URL

    }
}

`
I'm trying to build this loop to be able to accomplish this task and am completely stuck.

how does the uri end up looking? are the ips comma delimited or what? like: 'https://test.com/ips=1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,etc' ?

@SantiagoSquarzon yes, comma separated

Maybe "https://test.com/ips=$($IPs[0..1] -join ',')"?

If your list of IPs is provided as a single, ,-separated string rather than as an array (e.g., $IPList = '1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,...'), split it into an array first: $IPs = $IPList -split ','; if there can be spaces around ,: $IPs = ($IPList -split ',').Trim(). With this out of the way, there's no reason to update the existing answers, which assume an array as input. In general, please don't  change the requirements after answers have been given, especially not quietly (no one is notified by default).

A few asides: 'https://test.com/ips=$IPs' is a _verbatim_ string, due to to use of '...'quoting. To get$IPsto expand, you'd need"...". While the description of your problem is clear, the rest of the code is somewhat confusing ($IPs -ge 15, $IPs| Where-Object $_.count -gt 2), whether or not $IPs` is an array or a single string.


Here's a less efficient (due to not using StringBuilder), but more concise alternative to Santiago's helpful answer:
$IPs = @('1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4', '5.5.5.5')
$URLPrefix = 'https://test.com/ips='

$maxLen = 40
$thisUrl = $URLPrefix; $i = 0
foreach ($ip in $IPs + $false) {
  if (-not $ip -or $thisUrl.Length + $ip.Length -gt $maxLen) {
    # Last IP being processed or current URL can accept no more.

    $thisUrl # Output; make your Invoke-RestMethod call here.

    # Start the next URL
    $thisUrl = $URLPrefix; $i = 0
  }
  # Append the IP at hand.
  $thisUrl += (',',  '')[$i++ -eq 0] + $ip
}

Note:

If your list of IPs is provided as a single, ,-separated string rather than as an array (e.g., $IPList = '1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,...'), split it into an array first: $IPs = $IPList -split ','; if there can be spaces around ,: $IPs = ($IPList -split ',').Trim()

+ $false appends $false to the array of IPs, so as to ensure that the last URL constructed is also processed (this case is detected via -not $ip).

(',',  '')[$i++ -eq 0] is a Windows PowerShell-compatible approximation of a ternary conditional; in PowerShell (Core) 7, you can use $i++ -eq 0 ? '' : ','



$IPs + $false - I learned the expression “elephant in cairo``` yesterday (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant_in_Cairo) and then found one today :-).

@mclayton: :) Didn't know that term either. While certainly closely related and apt in the abstract, there is a subtle conceptual difference: here, the "elephant" ($false) doesn't ensure termination of the algorithm, but ensures that all results are processed.

Here is one algorithm you can use to construct your URIs, added bunch of comments to help you with the thought process:
$IPs = @('1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4', '5.5.5.5')
# define the max uri length
$maxLength = 40
# use an SB for efficient string building
$sb = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $IPs.Count; $i++) {
    # always append the base uri
    $sb = $sb.Append('https://test.com/ips=')
    # loop while there is a current item
    while ($current = $IPs[$i]) {
        # if the length of the string builder + current item
        # is greater than the max uri length
        if ($sb.Length + $current.Length -gt $maxLength) {
            # go back 1 position and break this loop
            $i--
            break
        }
        # else, append the current item and a comma
        $sb = $sb.Append($current).Append(',')
        # and increment the position
        $i++
    }

    # we have one chunk constructed here,
    # just removed the trailing comma and output the new string
    $sb.Remove($sb.Length - 1, 1).ToString()
    # clear the string builder and go to next iterantion
    $sb = $sb.Clear()
}

The output from this loop would be like:
https://test.com/ips=1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2
https://test.com/ips=3.3.3.3,4.4.4.4
https://test.com/ips=5.5.5.5

So from here, instead of outputting from the loop you could just pass the URI to Invoke-RestMethod or Invoke-WebRequest:
Invoke-RestMethod $sb.Remove($sb.Length - 1, 1).ToString()


Nice. I think you have an edge-case bug though - if $maxLength = 28 you’d expect https://test.com/ips=1.1.1.1(28 chars)  but your code includes the length of a non-existent comma and thinks it’s 29 chars, so just keeps looping. Probably not an issue the OP will hit in real use though, assuming a much larger $maxLength…

@mclayton good point. unless i'm missing something i think the + 1 can be removed actually

Here is a clear simple script:
$IPs = @('1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4', '5.5.5.5')

$i = 0
while ($IPs[$i]) {

    $URL = 'https://test.com/ips='

    while ($IPs[$i] -and ($URL + $IPs[$i]).Length -lt 40) {
        $URL += $IPs[$i] + ','
        $i++
    }

    $URL = $URL.TrimEnd(',')
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL

}


Great; thanks for updating.
